# Accord.NET (KNN) using F#: Distance Function

Tags: f#, accord.net

I am using Accord.NET in F# for the first time and I am having problems creating the function to calculate the distance for KNN.

Here is my code

```
static member RunKNN =
    let inputs = MachineLearningEngine.TrainingInputClass
    let outputs = MachineLearningEngine.TrainingOutputClass

    let knn = new KNearestNeighbors<int*int*int*int>(1,inputs,outputs,null)
    let input = 1,1,1,1
    knn.Compute(input)
```

When I swap out the null for a function like this

```
let distanceFunction = fun (a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int)
                           (e:int,f:int,g:int,h:int)
                           (i:float) ->
                           0
```

I get  an exception like this:

> *Error    1   This expression was expected to have type
>       System.Func<(int * int * int * int),(int * int * int * int),float>     but here has type
>       int * int * int * int -> int * int * int * int -> float -> int*

So far, the only article I found close to my problem is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/07/27/converting-system-func-lt-t1-tn-gt-to-fsharpfunc-lt-t-tresult-gt.aspx) one.  Apparently, there is a problem with how F# and C# handle delegates?

I posted this same question on the Google group for Accord.NET [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/accord-net/Ujb-quu7D9Q).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the distance function like this:

```
let distanceFunction (a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int) (e:int,f:int,g:int,h:int) =  
  0.0
```

(it takes two tuples in input and returns a float), and then create a delegate from it:

```
let distanceDelegate = 
  System.Func<(int * int * int * int),(int * int * int * int),float>(distanceFunction)
```

Passing this delegate to Accord.NET should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you should use the tuple form like so

```
let distanceFunction = fun ((a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int),
                           (e:int,f:int,g:int,h:int),
                           (i:float)) ->
```